# How to wait for user input for 5 seconds in python

Tags: python, keyboard

I am trying to process the contents of a file. I need ideas as to how to interact with
the user and to wait for a press of a key (s) to write the current line into another file. Thank you in advance.

```
with open(srcFile) as f:
    line = f.readline().strip()    
    #- do something with line

    #- part where I need help
    if s is press, write the current line to file
    if s is not pressed after 5 seconds, continue with the next line in srcFile
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the `time` and `keyboard` package for this case:

```
import time
import keyboard

start_time = time.time()  # Start the timer
key_pressed = False

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed("s"):
        key_pressed = True
        break

    if time.time() - start_time >= 5:
        break

if key_pressed:
    # write the current line to file
```

You might test with the above code to see the effect.

Comment: Did you check your CPU consumption while running this? This is also not a portable solution unless you're prepared to run it as super-user on macOS

Answer (score 1):

The keyboard module is not suitable for macOS unless the application is run with root privileges.

Here's a (hopefully) useful function that should work on any Unix variant (tested on macOS 13.5.2).

It has the added advantage of allowing for a timeout.

```
from os import read
from tty import setraw
from sys import stdin
from termios import tcsetattr, tcgetattr, TCSADRAIN
from select import select

def getchar(timeout: float|None = None) -> str|None:
    _fd = stdin.fileno()
    _attr = tcgetattr(_fd)
    try:
        setraw(_fd)
        _args = [[_fd], [], []] if timeout is None else [[_fd], [], [], timeout]
        _r, *_ = select(*_args)
        if _fd in _r:
            return read(_fd, 1).decode()
    finally:
        tcsetattr(_fd, TCSADRAIN, _attr)

# this will block indefinitely
c = getchar() 
print(c)

# this will block for 5 seconds
# if there is no input during that time, the function will return None
c = getchar(5)
print(c)
```